# eclipse build automatically modify

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, build-automation, gnu-make

I'd like eclipse to only run `make` in the directory the current file belongs to, not for the entire project. This becomes more important since the project is very big and `make` on the top level takes around 20 minutes. most of it is `entering-leaving directories` and `checking if build is needed` etc. So I have to manually open the directory in `cmd` and run `make`. So I'd like eclipse to do this in its `build automatically` process. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to play with **Build directory** option found in project properties *-> C/C++ Build -> Builder Settings* tab. The default value there is `${workspace_loc:/your_project}`. However Eclipse provides rich set of predefined variables (see under **Variables...** button). Probably most interesting for you are these ones:

- `build_files`

  > Returns the set of absolute file system paths whose modification caused the current build.  A list of the characters, 'a' (added), 'c' (changed), 'r' (removed), 'f' (files only), 'd' (directories only), can be supplied as an argument to limit the file list to just those types of deltas.  Defaults to all deltas.
- `selected_resource_loc`

  > Returns the absolute file system path of the selected resource.

Other places where you could try to use these variables are **Make build target** options in *Behaviour* tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add your build step to the External tools configuration, you could create a manual builder from that.

The External tools configurations are set similarly as the Run configurations, but allow executing different kind of steps (e.g. shell, Ant - I am reasonably sure, make-files can also be supported, but I don't use them - if not, then you can add a shell script that runs the make-file).

To set this up you have to go to the project properties (Right click on the project, select Properties), then go to the Builders page, and add a new builder, that is created from an External tool configuration.

I hope I was clear enough for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Select your project, open *Properties -> Builders*. Uncheck the builders that you don't want to run automatically anymore. Hit "New..." and select "External Program".

Now you can specify what command shall be run **automatically each time the project is built**. To have the parent directory of the currently selected file as an argument for your build command, you may use `${selected_resource_loc}\..`. See the *Variables* button for more such place holders that can be resolved at runtime.

Afterwards you may want to configure the "refresh" tab, if you also want to see newly created files in your project explorer. And if everything works well after some trial and error, you may also want to look at the "Build Options" tab to have it run in the background.